# Task Scheduler returns Directory Name Invalid for valid path

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to use Task Scheduler to run a Ruby script every night. When I try to run the script, I get error `0x8007010B` which seems to be [Directory Name Invalid](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3081.ad-cs-error-the-directory-name-is-invalid-0x8007010b-win32http-267.aspx). The directory I'm starting in is a mapped network drive. Performing the equivalent action from the command line works fine. Here's the action I'm trying to perform along with a piece of the command line window showing that both directory names are valid.

[image: Action configuration]

Why is Task Scheduler claiming the directory name is invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the issue by adding another Action in Task Scheduler to run `net use M: <path to network folder>`.

This task worked correctly when the computer was connected to a domain, but we took down our buggy domain server. For whatever reason, Task Scheduler used to know that M: was mapped to a network drive but now it doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem but more generic:
The `Start in (optional)` field doesn't support quotes (e.g. `"C:\Program Files"`).
I removed them and it worked!

Comment: There's an explanation with diagrams [here](http://matthewcevans.com/blog/2010/08/11/windows-task-scheduler-the-directory-name-is-invalid-0x8007010b/)